# How can I overclock my Pentium 4?

Tags: performance, cpu, overclocking, fsb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Overclock a Dell Inspiron 531?](https://superuser.com/questions/30179/how-to-overclock-a-dell-inspiron-531)
>   [How to overclock Dual-Core CPU E5200? Lacking options in BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/221513/how-to-overclock-dual-core-cpu-e5200-lacking-options-in-bios)

I have these specs from Everest:

CPU Properties

```
CPU Type - Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)
CPU Alias - Northwood
CPU Stepping - D1
Instruction Set - x86, MMX, SSE, SSE2
Original Clock - 2800 MHz
FSB Speed - 133 MHz
Min / Max CPU Multiplier - 21x / 21x
Package Type - 478 Pin uPGA
L1 Trace Cache - 12K Instructions
L1 Data Cache - 8 KB
L2 Cache 512 KB  (On-Die, ECC, ATC, Full-Speed)
CPU Physical Info   
Package Type    478 Pin uPGA
Package Size    3.50 cm x 3.50 cm
Transistors 55 million
Process Technology  6M, 0.13 um, CMOS, Cu, Low-K
Die Size    131 mm2
Core Voltage    1.475 - 1.55 V
I/O Voltage 1.475 - 1.55 V
Typical Power   38.7 - 89.0 W  (depending on clock speed)
Maximum Power   49 - 109 W  (depending on clock speed)
```

Front Side Bus Properties

```
Bus Type - Intel GTL+
Bus Width - 64-bit
Real Clock - 133 MHz (QDR)
Effective Clock - 533 MHz
Bandwidth - 4267 MB/s


Motherboard Name - Hewlett-Packard HP d530 SFF(PE095S)
Average temperature - 32C - 35C
```

There is no `Hardware monitor` or any other settings about overclock in my BIOS. Actually there are no settings at all, only few (Boot order, password, cooler speed).

I want to overclock FSB speed since I can't do a lot of things on my PC.

Yes, I have tried upgrading RAM, Hard drive but I i am sure that CPU is slowing system down.

I am 95% sure that it is possible to overclock this CPU. Also my CPU temperature is very cool and have no problems with heat.

So how can I overclock my current FSB speed or at least do something with performance?

Comment: It may be possible to overclock the CPU. But I doubt you can do it with that motherboard. Pre-built computers rarely have the functions needed to overclock the system made available in the BIOS.

Comment: @Dracs - can I transfer this CPU to friends motherboard, overclock it and than transfer back?

Comment: Overclocking is controlled by the motherboard. The CPU will run at what speed the motherboard tells it to run at. The only thing I can think of is finding an unofficial BIOS for your motherboard. But flashing a bad BIOS could ruin the motherboard (I'm assuming HP doesn't offer things like DualBIOS).

Comment: @techie007 Are you LOCA? It isn't a duplicate!!! Really other CPU, motherboard. Other situation!

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but it's the same basic question "Can I OC my motherboard that doesn't offer any BIOS configuration options" - Check out the answer there, as much of it applies.  Don't worry too much, it take 5 votes to close. Also see [How to overclock Dual-Core CPU E5200? Lacking options in BIOS?](http://superuser.com/questions/221513/how-to-overclock-dual-core-cpu-e5200-lacking-options-in-bios)

Comment: Atleast the question didn't get downvotes.

Comment: @LittleHelper Now It's up-voted